# jQuery Mobile put Lists in Center of page

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, center

I am creating an app using jQuery Mobile, and I have been trying to center my list views but can't seem to do it. I do not want my lists to start at the top of a page but in the center. Any way around this?

Also I am using the multipage template, pasting it here for easy reference

```
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my ID is beeing clicked.</p>      
    <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by lists? And you want them Vertically aligned?

Comment: jquery mobile, there is a layout type list view data-role="listview" . i want the lists to start in the center of the screen instead of on top

Comment: @user1053408 Why does your example code not have any lists in it? Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what you want, but if you want to change the location of an element, then CSS is where it's at:

```
html, body {
    height : 100%;
}
.ui-mobile .ui-page, .ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content {
    height : 100%;
}
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview {
    position : relative;
    top      : 50%;
}​
```

This makes the page atleast as big as the screen and then move the list-view widget down `50%`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/pr7h2/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want lists that are not full-width, see here:

Inset lists
If lists are embedded in a page with other types of content, an inset list packages the list into a block that sits inside the content area with a bit of margin and rounded corners (theme controlled). By adding the data-inset="true" attribute to the list (ul or ol), applies the inset appearance.